# Double superscript and \bar

Tags: superscripts, bar

it's several groups that I think of a solution for this little problem, but I can't find the optimal solution.

I did several tests, using some combinations, but without getting a good result.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mwe} 

%%---------------------Riduzione apici e pedici-------------------------------------- 
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \makeatletter
    \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
    \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
    \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
    \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
    \makeatother


    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $\bar{e}_{ij}'$
        \item $\bar{e}^{'2}_{ij}$
        \item $\bar{e'}^{2}_{\!\!ij}$
        \item $\bar{e}_{\!\!ij}^{'2}$
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

I would like to get a combination of 1 and 3, which is similar to the one in the box.

[image]

Could you give any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\bar e_{ij}'^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Incidentally, this is the same output as `$\bar e_{ij}^{\prime2}$`.  So you see, there is no double superscript, and TeX can figure that out if the `'` (which is a superscripted `\prime`) is given immediately prior to the rest of the superscript.

Comment: thanks, the right combination was missing. but why `\bar` and not `\bar{}`?

Comment: @Antonio In this case, there is no difference between the two.  However, in some cases, braces can prevent math information from being properly transferred to surrounding material.  For example, compare `$a - b$` to `$a {-b}$`, in terms of spacing.  In this case, the braces prevent the minus sign from knowing about the preceding `a` and therefore causing it to act as a negative rather than a minus.

Comment: `\bar{e}` has no problem and is better than `\bar e`, particularly when sub/superscripts follow. By the way, `{\bar{e}}` would do the same.

Comment: @Antonio Listen to egreg, not me.  He has chimed in on this train.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  thanks. these details are important. there is always something to learn. latex is a world and you are a fundamental resource for us inexperienced

Comment: @egreg your answer is very interesting, thanks